# IBM MQ cluster sender channels between 2 FR keep retrying

Tags: virtual-machine, ibm-mq

I ve created 2 hosts (1local and 1 on windows VM). Set everything according to screen to create cluster with goal to make clustered topic: [image: IBM MQ cluster topic host routing manual] So i added 2 FR and 6 PR queue mamangers and facing 2 problems:

1. I dont see FR2 in cluster directory, just system.tempqmgr which means its not connected
2. Sender channels keep retrying, as u can see **i can remote connect to other managers without problem**. Firewall is off, authentication type is none, no authentication records are created, managers are full repository. i tried recreate managers, authentications, clusters, turn on/off channels, nothing worked. Any ideas?

[image]

EDIT: I found out that even basic sender-receiver channels are not working. What can be problem?
[image]

In chat found out from OP the following error being reported:

```
9. 3. 2020 17:27:20 - Process(7292.1) User(MUSR_MQADMIN) Program(runmqchl.exe)
Host(DESKTOP-630J3C2) Installation(Installation1)
VRMF(9.1.0.0) QMgr(CTHFR1)
Time(2020-03-09T16:27:20.542Z)
ArithInsert1(852) ArithInsert2(437)

AMQ6047E: Conversion not supported.

EXPLANATION:
IBM MQ is unable to convert string data tagged in CCSID 852 to data in CCSID
437.
```

Comment: The FRs need manually defined `CLUSSDR` between them,  from the picture it does not indicate this,  can you confirm?

Comment: there was no difference when i manualy created all the channels in mqsc(senders and receivers) and this auto creating in IBM explorer(setting receivers and senders are made automatic)

Comment: It is a requirement to have manually defined `CLUSSDR` channels between each FR, in other words FRs must be manually fully connected to each other.  All PRs only need a `CLUSSDR` to one FR, the rest is auto defined.

Comment: Can the PRs connect to each other?  If not can you attempt a simple telnet test? Did you define listeners on each queue manager for the respective port?

Comment: well, i deleted auto-made sender channels and created it manually in mq explorer, but nothing changed. (or do i have to create them with mqsc?)

Comment: CTHFR1 has listener on port 1441 and FR2 on port 1442. i tried telnet 192.168.60.4 where is FR2 on port 1442 and connection failed

Comment: its weird, because sender channels on VM are running from PR to FR2. Just PR1 to PR2 which are on diferent hosts cant comunicate

Comment: That rules out MQ, you know the listener is working on the same host and telnet proves it is not reaching the other host via the network.   You need to troubleshoot the network issue, get a telnet to work, then worry about the MQ setup.

Comment: whats the difference with these sender channels connection and remote connection? i can remote connect to other host QM without problem

Comment: So from one host you can connect to some of the 4 ports on the 2nd host? Or do you mean you can connect to the other host on non-MQ ports?

Comment: in IBM MQ explorer, i can remote connect to all QM on other host. also sender channels are working inside hosts, but i cant get working sender channels between diferent hosts. 
about telnet, i cant telnet even localhost, can it be this problem?

Comment: What host and port do you specify to mq explorer?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209310/discussion-between-efysis-and-joshmc).

Comment: Can you answer above question? You would not specify the SCTQ as the transmission queue for a normal sender channel.

Comment: i have answered that question several times. so 4th or 5th time (also u see that on printscreen)
host1 - 192.168.43.169, FR1 port 1441
host2(VM) - 192.168.60.4, FR2 port 1442

Comment: Note that the OP noted in chat the telnet was not producing an error (like connection refused or timed out) it was just connected which is actually not an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After further discussion in chat the SO provided info from `CTHFR1`'s `AMQERR01.LOG` file.

The key info from this was the error below directly after the entry showing that the channel `TO.CTHRF2` started:

```
AMQ6047E: Conversion not supported.

EXPLANATION:
IBM MQ is unable to convert string data tagged in CCSID 852 to data in CCSID
437.
```

[CCSID 852 is a code page used under DOS to write Central European languages that use Latin script.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_852)

[CCSID 437 is the character set of the original IBM PC.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437)

This means that `CTHFR1` on the local PC is running with CCSID 852 and `CTHFR2` on the VM is running with CCSID 437.  I am not sure I understand why conversion is required since both the `CLUSSDR` and `CLUSRCVR` definitions provided in the chat had `CONVERT(NO)` set but I suspect it has to do with both queue managers being full repositories for the cluster.  In any case apparently IBM MQ on Windows can not convert from 852 to 437.  The suggested resolution to this problem is to set the CCSID of `CTHFR1` to 437 and restart.

```
ALTER QMGR CCSID(437)
```

The OP confirmed this resolved the issue.